# Module not found during installation

Tags: installation, installation-profiles

I am creating an install profile that requires, among other things, a slew of Features. Because of the intricacies of the project, which is a multi-site, I have in sites/mysite.com/modules/custom_features 3 different categories of features, each in its own folder: my_install_profile/, my_other_install_profile/, and common/.

Drupal seems to be finding all of the modules that my install profile requires just fine, except one. It's expecting to find it in sites/mysite.com/modules/custom_features/my_install_profile/ but the module actually lives in sites/mysite.com/modules/custom_features/common/.

I've triple-checked the install profile, and any dependent modules. I can't find anything path-specific, or specific to this module, that might be causing the confusion.

It doesn't report that the module is missing at the beginning of installation, but partway through I get this:

`Warning: include_once(umn_import_content_type.features.inc) [function.include-once]: 
      failed to open stream: No such file or directory in include_once() 
      (line 7 of /www/sites/mysite.com/modules/custom_features/my_install_profile/my_feature/my_feature.module).`

`Warning: include_once() [function.include]: 
      Failed opening 'my_feature.features.inc' for inclusion 
      (include_path='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.14/lib/php') in include_once() 
      (line 7 of /www/sites/mysite.com/modules/custom_features/my_install_profile/my_feature/my_feature.module).`

Why is Drupal looking for this in the wrong folder?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the issue was at the infrastructure level. The error resolved when I restarted Apache.